# feature release in production

Tags: git, github, version-control

Now we have two main branches: `develop`, which includes all the cutting edge features, and `master`, which is basically production ready. When we do production release, sometimes we just want to release some QA-passed features in `develop` to `master` and leave all the other features in `develop` to keep QAing. I know we can do `cherry-pick` from `develop` to `master`. But the problem is first, it's kind of tedious and mind-numbing to pick one by one. Second, this sometimes may create duplicate commits in your history as git doesn't understand those `cherry-pick`ed commits are actually the same. So is there any better clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a better way with your current workflow, but if you have different branches for different features then this becomes much easier. You could `merge` feature branches into `develop` for testing, make any necessary changes on the feature branch, then `merge` into `master` when it has passed QA. Merges will preserve branch history, allowing git to keep track of which commits have already been applied to different branches.

There's a good description of various [git workflows here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows), but it is a matter of opinion as to which is best.

Comment: We do have feature branches. But the problem is we always create feature branches out of develop branch instead of master. So still, we can not simply merge feature branch into master directly cause it may have some untested features from develop. So probably we should create feature out of master going forward?

Comment: Yes that will work. You could also have a branch of QA-passed features that haven't been merged into `master` yet and branch off from that (if you need certain features to develop other features). That would be in the territory of [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)